# Removing part of a string with grepl and str_sub in data.table

Tags: r, string, syntax, data.table

I tried removing the last four characters `2000`of a column of strings as follows:

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
DT <- structure(list(variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Percent of adults with less than a high school diploma, 2000", 
"Percent of adults with a high school diploma only, 2000", "Percent of adults completing some college or associate's degree, 2000", 
"Percent of adults with a bachelor's degree or higher, 2000", 
"Percent of adults with less than a high school diploma, 2014-18", 
"Percent of adults with a high school diploma only, 2014-18", 
"Percent of adults completing some college or associate's degree, 2014-18", 
"Percent of adults with a bachelor's degree or higher, 2014-18"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

                                                       variable
1: Percent of adults with less than a high school diploma, 2000
2: Percent of adults with less than a high school diploma, 2000
3: Percent of adults with less than a high school diploma, 2000



# If string contains 2000, remove last four characters.
DT <- setDT(DT)[grepl("2000", variable, fixed = TRUE), str_sub(variable, end=-4)]
```

However, apparently the syntax is not correct. What should the syntax be in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the changed value to `variable`.

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

DT[grepl("2000", variable, fixed = TRUE), variable := str_sub(variable, end=-4)]
```

Are you sure `end` should be -4 ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to strip off the year and possible range at the end of the `variable` column, then use `sub`:

```r
DT$variable <- sub(", \\d{4}(?:-\\d{2})?$", "", DT$variable)
```

### Demo